# How will this email look when it's send?

Tags: email, html-email

I was wondering something. How does this email look when it will be send true the PHP file?

`'Beste ' . $registration->voornaam . ',\n\n Bij deze ontvangt u uw ontvangstbevestiging voor uw inschrijving via het inschrijfformulier op www.lof.nl. \n\n Met vriendelijke groet, \n Stichting LOF Congres 2012');`

Wil it look like this?

```
Beste *name*,
Bij deze ontvangt u uw ontvangstbevestiging voor uw inschrijving via het inschrijfformulier op www.lof.nl.

Met vriendelijke groet,
Stichting LOF Congres 2012
```

If yes, thank you very much! Or if not, how can I change this? And is there an online environment where I can test this?

Thank you for your time,
Jordy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are your target email clients? If it is Outlook 2007+ you can test by creating a sample of the email and opening it up in Microsoft Word as they have the same rendering engine. For the others the best way is to save a sample down and get yourself accounts with the various free providers (gmail, yahoo, etc).

For anything Microsoft you will need to keep to very basic html. A good resource to how HTML renders in Microsoft is: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx). For your example above I would code it as:

```
'<p>Beste ' . $registration->voornaam . ',</p><p> Bij deze ontvangt u uw ontvangstbevestiging voor uw inschrijving via het inschrijfformulier op www.lof.nl. </p><p> Met vriendelijke groet, </p><p> Stichting LOF Congres 2012</p>');
```

But leaving the `\n` would probably give you about the same results.